# inchange the order of the summation

Tags: combinatorics

If we  inchange the order of the summation$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{r}\sum_{k=0}^{r}$$, what we can get？ the second order summation and the third order summation can inchange. but if we need the first order summation inchange the second summation and the third summation respectively. How can complete this process?

Answer (score 1):

We can get the following:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^r\sum_{k=0}^r f(r,j,k) &=& \sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^r\sum_{j=0}^r f(r,j,k) \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{r=j}^n\sum_{k=0}^r f(r,j,k) \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=k}^n\sum_{j=0}^r f(r,j,k) \\
&=& \sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=\max(k,j)}^n f(r,j,k) \\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{r=\max(k,j)}^n f(r,j,k).
\end{array}$$